# CSS Code to Center Button on Horizontal and Vertical

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to get this button I've created to be in the exact center of the page (vertically and horizontally). I've gotten it to center on the horizontal plane, but not on the vertical plain. Any help would be appreciated!

```
input#gobutton{
position: relative;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
cursor:pointer; 
padding:5px 25px; 
background:#87CEFA; 
border:1px solid #1E90FF; 
-moz-border-radius: 10px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0, .75);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0, .75);
box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0, .75);
color:#f3f3f3;
font-size:1.1em;
}
```

Comment: Please include a minimal, reproduceable example

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change position to absolute or fixed.

Comment: This made it centered, but now the button stretches all the way to the side of the page.

Comment: set a width for the button. I thought this was assumed. My bad.

Comment: Not sure why I have a -1 on this answer as it is the correct answer for the question??

Answer (score 0):

Input

Text-align: center;
Padding: 50px 0;

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp

Comment: Changing the padding made the button larger, but did not change where it was on the page.

Comment: I put text-align: center; into the code and it did not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's what you need, but take a look at this [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/1vtexu34/).

The CSS I used is:

```
input#gobutton{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    top: 40%;
    cursor:pointer; 
    padding:5px 25px; 
    background:#87CEFA; 
    border:1px solid #1E90FF; 
    -moz-border-radius: 10px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0, .75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0, .75);
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0, .75);
    color:#f3f3f3;
    font-size:1.1em;
}
```